# UnresolvedAddressException socket channel

Tags: java, sockets, nio, channel

I'm trying to create a socket between my computer and a remote server but I'm getting an `UnresolvedAddressException` error when I do this :

```
    InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("http://www.google.com", 80);
    SocketChannel serverChannel = SocketChannel.open(hostAddress);
```

Why is that?

Comment: The arguments to `new InetSocketAddress` are an optional hostname and a port number. A URL is not a hostname.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Chill, it was by mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use `http://` or `https://`, you just use:

```
InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com", 80);
```

Or you can use the IP address instead :

```
InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("216.58.210.228", 80);
```

Comment: and what about this example? host: detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt
I got java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Comment: this is not an correct hostname, for that you get this error, a file or url is not represent an ip address @NoeliaBelenLopez